# Alternative to tlsAlloc tlsGetValue and tlsSetValue

Tags: windows-phone-8, thread-local-storage

Is there any possible alternatives to TLS funcs.

I am trying to port from Windows desktop to Windows phone 8.

Comment: You are not alone in your suffering. Porting Crypto++ and OpenSSL to Windows Phone and Windows RT has been very painful. I can live without `TlsAlloc`, but the decision to remove `CryptGenRandom` (the unmanaged random number generator) is crushing. Sigh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no real TLS functions in Windows Phone 8. But you can simulate TLS in WP Runtime Component, take a look at this [ThreadEmulation](https://code.google.com/p/doubango/source/browse/branches/2.0/doubango/tinySAK/winrt/ThreadEmulation.cxx)